# WordPress не находит путь к стиля css и js

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, openserver

**Здравствуйте**

Устанавливаю WP на сайт и там не подгружаются стили, написал в **function.php**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и потом посмотрел на код страницы, там указывается другой путь, вот [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мой путь OSPanel\domains\qalab\wp-content\themes\qalab\assets\css\style.css

**Прошу помочь спасибо заранье**

Answer (score 0):

На скрине  путь из ядра вордпресс, у вас конечно будет другой. Также смотрите как называете стили и скрипты. Если уже есть с таким именем подключение то ваше пропустит, ну и функцию отделите от подключения.

```
function site_scripts_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/app.js',  array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_scripts_styles');
```